# Wrong status code in phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I always get status code 200/ok in my test case even if the requested page doen't exists.

```
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $kernel    = $client->getKernel();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/somethingnotexisting');
    $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

}
```

I am using phpunits with netbeans 7.1 and my symfony firewall is configure to allow only authenticated user. Otherwise they re redirected to the login page.

There is maybe some php.ini tuning to do ?

EDIT :

Here is the code i have from netbeans :

[image]

Comment: What statuscode do you get when you surf the page with your browser? Does it redirect you to the login page or do you get a 404? Maybe that's the problem!

Comment: Also consider using `assertEquals` instead of `assertTrue` for this : `$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());`. When this test will fail, you'll know which status code you had instead of 200.

Comment: When i browse an non existing page, i have an error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 3 days trying to resolve this.

I had downgrade my PHPUnit version from 3.6.11 to 3.5.14.

It works better with NetBeans now

Answer (score 5):

First do what @AdrienBrault suggested, use assertEquals:

```
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

This way you'll see what status code has been returned.

You're probably getting 301 or 302 (redirect) since functional test client doesn't redirect by default.

Try something like this:

```
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $kernel    = $client->getKernel();

    $client->request('GET', '/somethingnotexisting');
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#redirecting

Comment: The probleme is not into the test of the statuscode, but in the status code itself. I added a print screen to show you the statuscode i get even with a wierd url